# Is there a way to position email hints in certain browsers?

Tags: html, firefox

On [my website](http://www.thefunnyzone.co.uk/) if you click 'Register' and then enter something that is not an email (for example, simply 'asd') in the email input, and click 'Sign up' (just use anything for the password (eg 'Asdasd12')) Chrome displays a message telling you what is missing. Firefox attempts the same but if you do the same thing, it positions an awkward 'Please enter an email address.' hint in completely the wrong place.

Is there a way to tell each browser the best place to position these email hints?

(Note: the website is broken in IE but it still places the hint in the correct place, it's just firefox it seems.)

Firefox:Chrome comparison image:
[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code or screenshot in the question itself. Otherwise, once you fix your website, the link will be useless to future readers who come here with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm just editing the photo, it'll be up in a sec!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you already have hints for the various fields, the extra HTML5 validation hints are probably unnecessary. You can turn them off by adding a novalidate attribute to the form:

```
<form action="..." novalidate>
</form>
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/382) which seems to be similar to yours. In my Firefox the HTML5 validation hint is positioned correctly. I haven't been able to find a consistent cross-browser way to style HTML5 validation hints.

Incidentally the code on your page that shows / hides the form hints uses onfocusin and onfocusout events, which are not supported in Firefox (see [the W3schools explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusin.asp)). Changing these to onfocus and onblur will appropriately show/hide the hint in Firefox as well as the other browsers that are currently working correctly.

```
<input class="" id="email1" oninput="Check(1)" name="email1" placeholder="Email" maxlength="128" onfocus="Show('email-hint'); Move(1);" onblur="Hide('email-hint');" type="email">
```

Comment: Cheers! Many thanks for pointing out the error with Firefox compatibility too!